# Inherit from interface with different property type

Tags: c#, inheritance

I would like to do something like below in c#.
Is there any trick to do it?

```
interface IGenericRepository<T> {
    
}

interface IModel<T>{
    IGenericRepository<T> Repository { get; set; }
}

class ConcreteRepository : IGenericRepository<ConcreteModel>{

}

class ConcreteModel : IModel<ConcreteModel> {
    ConcreteRepository Repository { get; set; } /// this doesn't work
    /// IGenericRepository<ConcreateModel> Repository { get; set; } this would work 
}
```

I fixed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, that since `ConcreteModel` implements `IModel<ConcreteModel>` then
`ConcreteModel.Repository` *must* accept *any* class which implements `IModel<ConcreteModel>` not necessary `ConcreteRepository`,
i.e. the code below must be legal:

```
// Note, that MyOwnModel is not ConcreteModel
// But MyOwnModel implements IModel<ConcreteModel> 
public class MyOwnModel : IModel<ConcreteModel> {
  ...
}

...

ConcreteModel demo = new();

// Must be valid, since MyOwnModel does implement Model<ConcreteModel>
demo.Repository = new MyOwnModel();
```

If you want to have `ConcreteRepository Repository` while having `IModel<ConcreteModel>` implemented you can implement the interface
*explicitly*:

```
class ConcreteModel : IModel<ConcreteModel> {
  ConcreteRepository Repository { get; set; } 
            
  IGenericRepository<ConcreteModel> IModel<ConcreteModel>.Repository {
    get => Repository;
    set {
      //TODO: you should do something if value IS NOT ConcreteRepository
      // Here I've supposed that exception should be thrown
      Repository = value is ConcreteRepository concrete 
        ? concrete 
        : throw new ArgumentException("Value must be of ConcreteRepository type!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short - no, this would not be type safe. Imagine if you could - then the following would be possible:

```cs
class ConcreteRepository1 : IGenericRepository<ConcreteModel>{}

IModel<ConcreteModel> x = new ConcreteModel();
x.Repository = new ConcreteRepository1(); // but ConcreteModel works only with `ConcreteRepository`
```

What you can do - remove setter from interface (so the code is still type safe and you don't need type checks) and [explicitly implement it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

```cs
interface IModel<T>
{
    IGenericRepository<T> Repository { get; }
}

class ConcreteModel : IModel<ConcreteModel>
{
    public ConcreteRepository Repository { get; set; }
    IGenericRepository<ConcreteModel> IModel<ConcreteModel>.Repository => Repository;
}
```